# How to fill small holes in large region?

Tags: image-processing, binary, fill

the attached binary is the problem I am facing right now. I want to fill in the small white holes within the black region.I have tried to convert black and white and then use the imfill function, the problem is that it just fill all the white area including the large one in the middle. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!
[binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ZC1.png)

I tried the morphological erosion  and then dilation [dilated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ylQv.jpg) with se = strel('diamond',10); it indeed can fill the holes but also change the area of white and black separately, which would influence the results. Since I am going to use watershed to separate the clusters(black) and then count the number and area of them.I am confused how to use the opening and closing correctly.

Comment: Have you tried a morphological erosion?

Comment: A median filter could possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any specific tool, so I have had a try with **ImageMagick** just from the command-line. It is installed on most Linux distros and downloadable for free for OSX and Windows - it also has Python, Perl, .Net, PHP, node, Ruby, Java bindings and anything I do can be done in Matlab or OpenCV too.

Basically, I think you will need to downscale your image first to get decent results. I tried this:

```
convert holey.png -resize 10% -threshold 75% -median 3 \
    -morphology erode:2 disk:1.5                       \
    -morphology dilate:2 disk:1.5 -resize 3872x2592! result.jpg
```

That reduces the size down to 10% of the original, and thresholds out the resulting grey pixels and then applies a small median filter to remove noise. It then does an erosion followed by a dilation and scales the image back up, saving it as `result.jpg`.

[image]

I then made a little GIF animation to visualise the effect and see what it is actually doing, by running:

```
convert -delay 100 holey.png result.jpg animated.gif
```

[image]

Now that there are a smaller, more manageable number of white blobs, you could then run a *"Blob Analysis"* or *"Connected Components"* and remove any blobs below a size/area threshold of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you want only want to fill the holes within the dark area. So first you have to find black area or delete the white area (temporarily).

1. Connected component labeling only on white patterns.
2. Find the biggest white pattern
3. Erase the biggest white pattern and save it.
4. Fill holes as you already tried.
5. Put back the biggest white pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your suggestions! I have work it out and now are working on the segmentation of the aggregates. But before this step, I need to mask the modified binary image to the initial RGB image and show the difference after several operations.